# On some special actions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group and $A$ be an abelian group. Let $\beta$, $\alpha :G\rightarrow Aut(A)$ be two homomorphisms. It is well known that if there
exist $\sigma \in Aut(A)$, $\rho \in Aut(G)$ such that $(\beta \circ
\rho )(g)=\sigma \circ \alpha (g)\circ \sigma^{-1}$ for all $g\in G$, then the semidirect products $A\rtimes _{\alpha
}G$ and $A\rtimes_{\beta}G$ are isomorphic.

However, in one stage of a proof concerning the representation of some special groups, I get that there
exist $\sigma \in Aut(A)$, $\rho \in $ $Aut(G)$ such that $(\alpha \circ
\rho )(g)=\sigma \circ \alpha (g)\circ \sigma^{-1}$ for all $g\in G$. Is there
any interpretation of this formula in group theory? why this might be an interesting property?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One stage of a proof of WHAT?  Also, you should edit the closed version instead of asking a fresh question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've let $\beta=\alpha$.  So of course this is true with $\sigma$ and $\rho$ the identity automorphisms.  But this is basically a trivial statement.

Not sure whether anything can be done with it if $\sigma\ne\rho$.  If there are any examples, I guess they could be called $\alpha$ -equivalent

Comment: If I understand, you mean by your answer that if $(\alpha \circ \rho )(g)=\sigma \circ \alpha (g)\circ \sigma^{-1}$ then $\rho$ and $\sigma$ must be the identity automorphisms..

Comment: That's one way that works, at least.

Comment: Thank you Chris. What we can  deduce if we assume that $G=\left\langle g\right\rangle $ is a cyclic group of order
$n$?.

Comment: I do know what the automorphism group  is then.  That is, $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_n)\cong \Bbb Z_n^\times$.

Comment: Yes. I mean what we can deduce from the equation $(\alpha \circ \rho )(g)=\sigma \circ \alpha (g)\circ \sigma^{-1}$ if we assume that G is a cyclic goup.

Comment: I get $\sigma \in N_{Aut(A)}(\alpha(G))$ for G cyclic. Is this interpretation true?

Comment: Maybe if $\rho$ is the identity.  And I don't see that $G$ being cyclic matters here.

Comment: Let $G=\left\langle g\right\rangle $, there exists an integer $s\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\rho(g)=g^{s},$ where $(s,m)=1$. Then $\alpha(G)=\left\langle \alpha(g)^{s}\right\rangle$. Therefore $(\alpha \circ\rho )(g)=\sigma \circ \alpha (g)\circ \sigma^{-1}$ implies that $\alpha(G)=\sigma \circ \alpha (G)\circ \sigma^{-1}$. Therefore $\rho$ is not necessary the identity